# Print form values

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have the following form. I need to print the value the user entered for textfiled `uname` ? How can i do this ?

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Basic Form',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    bodyPadding: 5,
    width: 350,

    // Any configuration items here will be automatically passed along to
    // the Ext.form.Basic instance when it gets created.

    // The form will submit an AJAX request to this URL when submitted
    url: 'save-form.php',

    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'NAME',
        name: 'uname'
    }],

    buttons: [{
        text: 'Submit',
        handler: function() {
            // The getForm() method returns the Ext.form.Basic instance:
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if (form.isValid()) {

                // CONSOLE.LOG (FORM VALUES) ///////////////////////////////////////

            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [getValues](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-getValues) method to get an object containing all of the field values in the form:

```
var form = this.up('form').getForm();
if (form.isValid()) {
    var values = form.getValues();

    // log all values.
    console.log(values);

    // log uname value.
    console.log(values['uname']);
}
```

Alternatively, use the [findField](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-findField) method to access a specific field within the form:

```
var form = this.up('form').getForm();
if (form.isValid()) {

    // log uname value.
    var field = form.findField('uname');
    console.log(field.getValue());
}
```

---

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/5hndW/